# Parse error: syntax error

Tags: php

I keep getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'" on the first line, I've tried breaking the string up, but then it doesn't embed properly. Anybody know how to sort this?

```
protected $_embedHTML = array('youtube' => '<object width="425" height="350"
                                            type="application/x-shockwave-flash" '.
                                            'data="http://www.youtube.com/'.$value.'">'.
                                            '<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/'.$value.'">
                                            </param>'.
                                            '<!--[if IE]>'.
                                            '<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/'.$value.'"'.
                                            'type="application/x-shockwave-flash"'.
                                            'wmode="transparent" width="425" height="350" />'.
                                            '<![endif]-->'.
                                            '</object>');
```

Comment: You're using the concanation operator (`.`). That will not work in class member variables. Use an approperiate constructor function instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't concatenate data in a class variable definition that way. The initialization value has to be a constant.

Try this:

```
protected $_embedHTML;

function __construct() {
  $this->_embedHTML = array('youtube' => '<object width="425" height="350"
      type="application/x-shockwave-flash" '.
      data="http://www.youtube.com/'.$value.'">'.
      '<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/'.$value.'">
      </param>'.
      '<!--[if IE]>'.
      '<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/'.$value.'"'.
      'type="application/x-shockwave-flash"'.
      'wmode="transparent" width="425" height="350" />'.
      '<![endif]-->'.
      '</object>');
}
```

Or, strip the concatenation and simply make it a multiline string. I'm not sure why you're not doing this, as it is already composed of multiline strings.